# SQL query in a PHP based website

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

I have a table for files with 3 rows: name, desc, user.

Name is the name of the file, for example: cert1.pdf
Desc is a description of the file, for example: First exam of the year.
User is the name of the user who uploaded the file to the server, for example: John Doe.

Now I want to retrieve the name and the description of cert1.pdf. So this is what I got:

```
$sql = "SELECT desc, user
    FROM files AS f
    WHERE f.name = 'cert1.pdf'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
```

It must be something really stupid, but I keep having this error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'desc, user FROM files AS f WHERE f.name = 'cert1.pdf'' at line 1

Any idea of what am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

desc is a reserved words try putting desc inside back ticks (`) the same key as the ~
 instead of desc
user might be a reserved word too

try

```
SELECT `desc`,`user`
```

Comment: Well spotted. I would avoid calling columns reserved words altogether.

Comment: popnoodles how did you get the back ticks to show in a comment?

Comment: test comment \`desc\`

Comment: THANK YOU... haha didn't know desc was a protected word. It worked 100% fine now. You sir just saved me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: `user` is not a reserved word => http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html - however there are a few words that do resemble (it), but is indeed not a reserved word; `desc` is. ;-) - It is good practice to use backticks for both, but not necessary for unreserved words.

Answer (score 2):

To show an example of Tin Tran's answer of escaping "desc" with backticks.

```
$sql = "SELECT `desc`, `user`
    FROM files AS f
    WHERE f.name = 'cert1.pdf'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
```